# Use ffmpeg to time-dilate and resample audio without changing frequencies

Tags: ffmpeg, sox, ntsc

I have some audio (wave file) that is sampled at a rate of 48000 samples per second.

This audio was created to match a 30 FPS video.  However, the video actually plays back on the target at the NTSC framerate of 29.97 (30 X 1000/1001).

This means that I need to time-dilate the audio so that there are 48048 samples where there were previously 48000 samples (it plays back 1.001 times slower) but still maintains that the final audio file's rate is 48000 samples per second.

Ideally, also, I'd like to do this resample using the sox library option for FFMPEG since I hear it has much higher quality.

Can anyone help me with the command line necessary to process a file in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af asetrate=47952,aresample=48000:resampler=soxr out.wav
```

This assumes that libsoxr is linked.

Comment: Thank you.  However, 47952 is slightly inexact (it will cause audio to drift by about one frame every 5 hours).  Is there a way to do something like 'asetrate=48000,aresample=48048' but still have it write the output file with a rate of 48k which would be more exact if you had a very long audio file?

Comment: I think, it's 1 frame every 9 hrs. Anyway, invert the order: `-af aresample=48048:resampler=soxr,asetrate=48000,`

Comment: You're right -- at 30 FPS it's ~ 9 hours.  I did the calculation using 60 FPS / 59.94 to get the ~5 hours number.